# How to get fetch values from property file i n Spring

Tags: spring

I want to fetch the values of property file which is as below:-
The name of the property file is **application.properties** and the values are as below:-

```
config.name=abcd
config.pwd=efgh
```

My code where it will retrieve the values are as below:-

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")

    public class CustomerService {
    @Value("${config.name}")
    private String name;

    @Value("$(config.pwd)")
    private String data;

    System.out.println("name is ::" +name);
    System.out.println("data is ::" +data);
    }
```

But when the code is returning the output is coming as

```
name is ::ankita
data is ::$(config.pwd)
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use  : `@Value("${config.pwd}")`